# adding initial value to Django model form

Tags: django

I just want to add an initial value to one field when it gets populated, this is my view

```
def add_program(request):
    module = Module.objects.all()
    last_item = Programme.objects.filter(module_id__in=module).last()
    if last_item:
        day = last_item.day + 1
    else:
        day = 1
    initial_data = {
        'day': day
    }
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ProgramAddForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None, initial=initial_data)
        if form.is_valid():
            instance = form.save(commit=False)
            instance.save()
            return redirect('program_add')
    else:
        form = ProgramAddForm()
    return render(request, 'client_apps/program/form.html', {'form': form})
```

and form

```
class ProgramAddForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Programme
        fields = ['module', 'day', .........]
```

even though initial value is passed nothing is visible in day field when form populates, is there any alternative method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because you only use it in case of the *POST* request, not the *GET* request:

```
def add_program(request):
    module = Module.objects.all()
    last_item = Programme.objects.filter(module_id__in=module).last()
    if last_item:
        day = last_item.day + 1
    else:
        day = 1
    initial_data = {
        'day': day
    }
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ProgramAddForm(request.POST, request.FILES, initial=initial_data)
        if form.is_valid():
            instance = form.save()
            return redirect('program_add')
    else:
        form = ProgramAddForm(initial=initial_data)  # ← initial data for a GET request
    return render(request, 'client_apps/program/form.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: may I ask, how it can be done with class based views?

Comment: @bmons: you override the `get_initial` method (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormMixin.get_initial) and return a dictionary in that method that thus maps keys to values like you do in the function-based view here.

Comment: I didn't do anything for me. I have a **OneToOneField**.

Comment: I used a **Class Based View**, but now when I changed to a **Function Based View** it works.

Answer (score 0):

you can add it in the init method

```
class ProgramAddForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(YoutubeModelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields["day"].value = "day"
        self.fields["day"].initial = "day"
        self.fields["day"].initial = "padding-top: 0;"

        class Meta:
             model = Programme
```

this to load in the form and in the admin of django